# Solidity - multiple oracle queries with different parameters each

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-invocation, chainlink

I have managed to get a API call for the JSON file and return the data from the specific location that I want.

Now the problem is, that if multiple people try to get the data for different locations in the JSON file, only the last is returned. So if 4 people roughly simultaneously call the function, only  4 ist getting the desired data, number 1, 2 and 3 do not get anything

is there a way to safely get the data for each call?

Comment: Why 2 and 3 get bad data? It doesn't seem to be a problem with Solidity, more like the JSON processing has a bug.

Comment: I´m not quite sure, I believe that the chainlink oracle will only report the last request that was sent. I was wrong, only the last one gets back will edit now

Comment: I haven't used chainlink for that kind of thing. Perhaps if you can modify the endpoint use some id as part of the path so for the oracle they all will look for different endpoints. e.g. `/api/query/{id}`.